# checkbox use label without id (label css can change)

Tags: css

```
<style>
input[type=checkbox]{display:none}
label{color: black;}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{color:red;}
</style>

<label><input type="checkbox">Click</label>
```

I have a checkbox use label to click, when check box clicked, the label should change the color. What I try to achieve is `do it without for="id"`. I place input inside of label, but the color wont change.

Is any way to do this without id?

Comment: This can't work, precisely because your `input` is inside the `label`, and to make it work would require a parent-selector (which CSS lacks, unfortunately); you could wrap the text in a `span`, however, and style that sibling element, using the adjacent sibling (`+`) selector.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a hack but you can use something like this:

With input outside label..

```
<input type="checkbox"><label>Click</label>

input[type=checkbox] { 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
}
label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    color: black;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    color: red;
}
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/96v7C/

Answer (score 1):

If anyone stumbles over this old question I'd like to pick up Vangel Tzo's answer and optimize it a bit. I would recommend to switch `position:absolute;` and `position:relative;` for the `label` and `input` fields to allow longer text to wrap properly without overlapping any content below it:

```css
.hidden-checkboxes {
  font: 14px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.hidden-checkboxes input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 30px;
}
.hidden-checkboxes label {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.hidden-checkboxes input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  background: #3298dc;
  color: white;
}

.hidden-checkboxes div {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden-checkboxes" style="width:300px;">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox"><label>Check me please.</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox"><label>Or how about me?</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox"><label>How about some long text that will cause wrapping of text?</label>
  </div>  
</div>
```

*Remark:* Font and `margin-bottom` are only used for styling the demo.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a compleat radio butons and checkbox example.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7M4Z/)

```
/*style for iinpul checkbox*/
 input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}
input[type=radio] + label, input[type=checkbox] + label {
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #FFFFFF 20%, #F6F6F6 50%, #EEEEEE 52%, #F4F4F4 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 padding-box rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #FFFFFF inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    color: #444444;
    display: block;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 34px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 13px;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label, input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background-image: none;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    background-color:#e0e0e0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.c-custom-checkbox {
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.c-custom-checkbox input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.c-custom-checkbox .c-custom-checkbox__img {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.c-custom-checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + .c-custom-checkbox__img {
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<label class="c-custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="valueCheck" />
  <i class="c-custom-checkbox__img"></i>Some Label
</label>
```